# i am trying to sort a concatenated list of arrays

Tags: python, list, sorting, integer, concatenation

I am trying to sort a concatenated list of arrays

```
k1 = 15 19 3
k2 = 12 13
```

my code is :

```
k1 = input().split()
k2 = input().split()
l = k1 + k2
x = l . sort()
print(x)
```

the output is `['12', '13', '15', '19', '3']`
I do not know why the number 3 ends last after doing ascending order.
i want the number 3 placed first in ascending order
kindly give the correct code

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of strings, which get sorted alphabetically.  If you want a list of ints, which get sorted numerically, do:

```
x = sorted(int(n) for _ in range(2) for n in input().split())
print(x)
```

which gives you:

```
15 19 3
12 13
[3, 12, 13, 15, 19]
```

Comment: i am unable to understand what you have written.  i want the number 3 placed first in ascending order

Comment: Did you try running the code?  It does that.